# way to create a folder after DatePattern within Log4j.xml

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Need some help to see if its possiale to create a folder after a DatePattern?

In the first example, you can see that it will create a httplog under `C:/Program Files/program/Logs/<Date>/httplog`:

```
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <param name="rootDir" value="C:/Program Files/program/Logs/" />
    <param name="componentId" value="HTTPlog" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd" />
```

Is there a way to add a folder after a date so the above will log to;

```
C:/Program Files/program/Logs/Date/Folder2/httplog
```

Comment: Which version of log4j are you using? Log4j **1.x** or Log4j **2**?

Answer (score 0):

From the config file name and format snippet in your question I assume you are using log4j-1.2's DailyRollingAppender. May I suggest you switch to log4j2? The RollingFileAppender or RollingRandomAccessFileAppender make what you want to do fairly easy.

Note that the configuration file needs to be named log4j2.xml and the syntax is a little different. The manual has many [examples](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender).

Log4j2 has an adapter (log4j-1.2-api) whose jar you can drop in the classpath, and your application's calls to the log4j-1.2 API will be routed to the Log4j2 implementation. (You do need to remove the old log4j-1.2.x.jar file from the classpath.)